# Magento2.3.4 - After upgrade Magento2.3.2 to Magento 2.3.4 order email showing wrong format

Tags: magento2.3.4

I am using php7.1
after upgrade magento2.3.2 to magento 2.3.4 order email showing below

> =0A=0A=0A =0A =0A =0A =0A=0A=0A
> =0A=0A=0A=0A=0A
> =0A   =0A =0A =0A =20=
> =0A
> =0A =0A =20= 3D"JOTEX"=20==0A =0A =20=    =0A
> =0A
> =0A <= !-- Begin Content -->=0D=0A=0D=0A=0D=0A =0D=0A =0D=0A
> =0D=0A
> =0D=0A pradeep singh,=0D=0A
>
> =0D= =0A Thank you for your order from COMPANY.=0D=0A =20= Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number.=0D=0A =20=
>
> =0D=0A
> =0D=0A If you have questions about your order, yo= u can email us at test.=0D=0A =0D=0A
>
> =0D=0A
> =0D=0A
> =0D=0A <= h1 style=3D"font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.1; font-size: 26px; margin-= top: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
> margin-bottom: 10px; padding-b= ottom: 10px;">Your Order
>
> ## 000000118=0A=0D=0A Pla= ced on February 19, 2020 9:03:59 AM GMT+02:00
>
> =0D=0A    =0D=0A
> =0D=0A
> =0D=0A =20= =0D=0A =0D=0A =20= =0D=0A =20=
> =0D=0A
> =0D=0A =20= Billing Info
> =0D=0A =20= pradeep singh=
> =0Atest
> =0Anear
> =0A=0A=0A=0Abikaner, New York, 94024
> =0AJo= rdan
> =0AT: 01234567890=0A=0A
>
> =0D=0A =0D=0A =0D=0A  =0D=0A pradeep singh
> =0Atest
> =0Anear
> =0A=0A= =0A=0Abikaner, New York, 94024
> =0AJordan
> =0AT: 01234567890=0A=0A=0D=0A
> =0D=0A =0D= =0A
> =0D=0A
> =0D=0A Payment Method
> =0D=0A = =0A Cash On Delivery
> =0A=0A=0D=0A =20= =0D=0A =0D=0A   =0D=0A Shipping Method
> =0D=0A Aramex - Overnight (Parcel)
>
> =0D=0A =20= =0D=0A    =0D=0A =20= =0D=0A
> =0D=0A
> =0D=0A =20= =0A =0A =0A =0A= =0A =0A =0A= =0A
> =0A =0A
> =0A =20= Items    =0A =0A Qty =0A =20=    =0A Price <= /th>=0A
> =0A =0A =20=
> =0A TALAN 112 HIGH ANKLE
>
> = =0A
> =0A =20= Sizes=0A=0A 40=0A=0A =0A =20=
>
> =0A   1   =0A =0A =0A $ 29.95=0A =0A=0A   =0A
> =0A
> =0A =20=
> =0A =20= Subtotal =0A =0A $ 29.95 =20=    =0A
> =0A
> =0A Cash on De= livery    =0A =0A =20= $ 2.82 =20=    =0A
> =0A
> =0A Shipping & Ha= ndling =0A =0A =20= $ 5.38 =0A
> =0A
> =0A Grand Total=0A =20=   =0A =0A $ 38.15= =0A    =0A
> =0A
> = =0A
> =0A =0D=0A    =0D=0A
> =0D=0A
> = =0D=0A=0D=0A=0D=0A=0D=0A
> =0D=0A
> =0D=0A About us

Comment: Have you got any email extensions install?

Comment: Please run 'php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer' to show errors

Comment: I am having Mageplaza extension